# Loop through TSV/CSV file stops after run

Tags: python, csv

I got a problem regarding a loop that collects data from a TSV/CSV file. 
The thing is that I check whether the userid is within my tsv file and if it is just do a regular print. But the thing is that it does not add up.

Let me explain myself by using the code that I have untill now:

```
import csv
with open("source/to/file.tsv") as tsvfile:
        tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
        for i in range(1,10):
            for columns in tsvreader:
                userid = 1
                column1, column2, column3 = columns
                if userid == int(column1):
                    print("userid:", userid,"result: ", int(column1), int(column2), int(column3))
                    userid += 1
```

Whenever I run this code it will output:

```
-- userid: 1 result:  1 3098 1
-- userid: 1 result:  1 508 1
-- userid: 1 result:  1 889 1
-- userid: 1 result:  1 802 0
-- userid: 1 result:  1 3800 0
```

The problem starts here. Because I expect that my userid is added up with value 1. My userid will be 2 and the loop will start again and will print out something like:

```
-- user id 2 result: ...
-- user id 2 result: ...
-- user id 2 result: ...
```

But my code does not do that. Anyone knows why?

*Note that: userid 2 is within my TSV file so that is not the problem!*

---

**Extra info:** in my tsv file I have the following situation:

```
1   802     0
1   3800    0
2   7492    1
2   5235    0
```

I want to output all the results that belong to userid1 (802,3800 etc), after that the loops must continue to output all the results for userid2 (7492,5235 etc). Later in the process I want to store for each userid their results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your code does not progress beyond userid 1 is explained in [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31537650/21945).

It seems to me that your intention is to print all rows for userid 1, then all rows for userid 2, and so on. And the range on the outer loop suggests that you want to display rows for user ids 1 through 9.

One problem though is that once all rows from the CSV file are consumed, the `for columns in tsvreader` loop will no longer have anything to iterate over, and so its body will not execute. Nothing further will be displayed. That can be overcome by "rewinding" the input file with `seek()`.

Fixing those bugs results in this code:

```
import csv

with open("source/to/file.tsv") as tsvfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for userid in range(1,10):
        tsvfile.seek(0)    # back to the start of the CSV file
        for columns in tsvreader:
            column1, column2, column3 = columns
            if userid == int(column1):
                print("userid:", userid,"result: ", int(column1), int(column2), int(column3))
```

I *think* that is what you are after. For example on input (I've used commas as the separator):

```
2,4,4
1,2,3
1,4,5
2,8,8
1,6,7
2,2,2
4,1,1
8,1,2
10,4,0
1,0,1
4,4,4
3,3,3
```

The output would be:

```
userid: 1 result:  1 2 3
userid: 1 result:  1 4 5
userid: 1 result:  1 6 7
userid: 1 result:  1 0 1
userid: 2 result:  2 4 4
userid: 2 result:  2 8 8
userid: 2 result:  2 2 2
userid: 3 result:  3 3 3
userid: 4 result:  4 1 1
userid: 4 result:  4 4 4
userid: 8 result:  8 1 2
```

Note that data for userid 10 is not included as that is outside of the range of userids.

I have had to guess your intentions, however, if I am correct, what you want to do is group the data by userid and display that in sorted order. A better way is simply to sort all the data in one go:

```
import csv

with open("source/to/file.tsv") as tsvfile:
    data = sorted(list(csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')),
                  key=lambda row: int(row[0]))
    for column1, column2, column3 in data:
        print("userid:", column1, "result: ", int(column1), int(column2), int(column3))
```

Output:

```
userid: 1 result:  1 2 3
userid: 1 result:  1 4 5
userid: 1 result:  1 6 7
userid: 1 result:  1 0 1
userid: 2 result:  2 4 4
userid: 2 result:  2 8 8
userid: 2 result:  2 2 2
userid: 3 result:  3 3 3
userid: 4 result:  4 1 1
userid: 4 result:  4 4 4
userid: 8 result:  8 1 2
userid: 10 result:  11 4 0
```

If you really want to exclude user ids outside of a given range, do this:

```
import csv

with open("source/to/file.tsv") as tsvfile:
    data = sorted(list(csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')),
                  key=lambda row: int(row[0]))
    userids = range(1,10)
    for column1, column2, column3 in data:
        if int(column1) in userids:
            print("userid:", column1, "result: ", int(column1), int(column2), int(column3))
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I want and the explanation is very helpful! Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you also perhaps tell me how I should output each user_id to a seperate csv/tsv file? Or is that impossible @mhawke

Comment: It is possible, of course. As you iterate over the sorted data keep track of the current user id. Open a CSV file and start writing each row to it. When the user id changes open a new CSV file and write to that. It might be helpful to use a dictionary with user ids as keys to help group the data for each user in a list. Then iterate over the keys of the dictionary writing the data for each to a file. Burhan Khalid's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31538379/21945) made use of a defaultdict to group the data for each user - you could base your code off that.

Answer (score 2):

The code resets userid for each row (i.e., inside the `for columns in...` loop). If you move that line outside that loop, I believe it will do what you want.

Comment: Yep, it will add up. but the problem with that is does only output: 1 result of  userid1 and 1 result of userid2 and I want to output all the results of userid1 and all the results of userid2 etc ;)

Comment: Ah, I see - [mhawke's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31538708/215009) above covers that well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what you try to do, as Rob Hague said you keep `userid` to 1...

A wild guess about what you want:

```
userid = 1
tsv = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter='\t')
for i, row in enumerate(tsv):
    if i > 10:
        break
    if str(userid) == row[0]:
        print 'userid: %d result: %s' % (userid, row)
        userid+= 1
    else:
        print 'not found: %s' % (row,)
```

**Edit**

The easy way (i don't use the `csv` module in the example since you does not seems to need it), but use more memory.

```
# load all data
import collections

data = collections.defaultdict(list)

for line in open(filename):
        row = line.strip().split('\t')
        data[int(row[0])]+= [row[1:]]

# output data grouped by user
for userid, row in data.iteritems():
        print 'userid: %d result: %s' % (userid, row)
```

The other simple way (assuming data is **sorted** by userid), outputing result as soon as possible and using slightly less memory.

```
def show(userid, row):
    print 'userid: %s result: %s' % (userid, row)

current = ''
data = []
for line in open(filename):
    row = line.strip().split('\t')
    if row[0] != current:
        if data:
            show(current, data)
            del data[:]
        current = row[0]
    data+=[row]

show(row[0], data)
```

If the data is unsorted and you have memory issues, you can store positions in a dictionary and `seek` through it (see the [file objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) documentation).

Comment: I added some extra info to my question. Perhaps you understand it now ;)

Comment: Oh, you want to seek through the file... i'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
1   802     0
1   3800    0
2   7492    1
2   5235    0
```

> I want to output all the results that belong to userid1 (802,3800
>   etc), after that the loops must continue to output all the results for
>   userid2 (7492,5235 etc). Later in the process I want to store for each
>   userid their results.

You can easily accomplish what you are trying to achieve by using a dictionary:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

results_by_id = defaultdict(list)

with open('somefile.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
   for row in reader:
       results_by_id[row[0]].append(list(map(int, row[1:])))

for userid, results in results_by_id.iteritems():
   print('{} has {} total results'.format(userid, len(results)))
   for result in results:
       print('\t {}'.format(result))
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? How is the userid been set?